# IOS limitations when running on background

Tags: ios, background-process

I searched informations about possibilities when running an iOS app on background, but I didn't found same on different sites.

My application has to read the battery level (with step of 1%) and the time, but I don't know if I can read that when running on background.

Please if someone is sure about it or know a site to read these infos, it will be very nice.

EDIT : I've one more question, can I just open my app (to perform more actions) when the notification center return a battery state under 5% for example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, you can't.**

It's not possible to let your app running on background, it's iOS system's limitations.

In iOS 7.0 and later, you have opportunity to do some pre-fetch stuff even your app is not running, through the method like `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:`, but you should tell the device by posting remote notification from your server.

Comment: That's incorrect. Apple introduced background app refresh in iOS 8.0

Comment: Like I said, everyone has a different answer about it. So is it really possible ?

Comment: @Shai Background app refreshing can be done in iOS 7.0 and above, but can only be triggered through notifications, app is still unable to do self-launch. If I'm wrong, please bring it on with some reference or anything else.

Comment: I found a solution with the notification center but it's seem to be impossible because it doesn't look at the battery level when the app run in background. So I guess it's impossible even with iOS 9 ?

Comment: @Krili I believe that the iOS design pattern will never let applications run on background.

Comment: Background fetch is possible. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html